# a time function in C linux

Tags: c, linux, function, time

hi i was wondering if it is possible to edit the time function.for my program to give a time for a user to retry again?

```
struct tm * abc()
{
char *time_string;
time_t curtime;
struct tm *loctime;

/* Get the current time.  */
curtime = time (NULL);

/* Convert it to local time representation.  */
loctime = localtime (&curtime);
return loctime;
}
```

this will return the current time but want i want to do is to edit this to add a value. The reason for me doing this is so i can tell a user to try again at a certain time using the current and adding 2minutes to it. Not sure if this is the correct way?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

time() returns a timestamp in seconds (number of seconds since [the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch)), so you can just add the required delay.

```
curtime = time (NULL) + 2*60; // Adds two minutes,
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines just before the return.

```
  localtime->tm_min += 2;
  mktime(localtime);
```

The first line adds two minutes to localtime.
The second line renormalizes localtime to a "standard" format, in other words you it will roll the added minutes from values like (61) to values like (hours+1),(minutes = 1).

Comment: thanks for you help i found some information after posting, so i am now doing it very similarly to the method posted. Thanks

Comment: @Edwin: Presumably you meant `+=` on the first line.

Comment: @Tomalak and @user641902, yes I had a typo.  It should have been `tm_min += 2` and not `tm_min + 2`.  Thank you for your observations, and it's been corrected in the post

Comment: Still seems like an OTT solution, recalcing the entire time when you can just increment the UNIX timestamp before generating the time in the first place. It may be useful in more general cases, but not for adding two minutes.

Comment: @Tomalak, two minutes today, a week tomorrow.  Which one is going to be easier to maintain?  In 2038 you'll be glad you didn't rely solely on the long.

Comment: @Edwin: In 2011 I'll be glad I'm not wasting all these CPU cycles for no reason, if my application is time-critical. Keep the function properly isolated as in the OP's question and it'll be a doddle to modify in the future if the need arises.